# Правильно ли подобраны родственные слова к омонимам?

Tags: омонимы

Проверьте, пожалуйста! Правильно ли я начала делать?

Подберите родственные слова к данным омонимам. Какой вывод о свойствах омонимов можно сделать на основании полученных вами словообразовательных рядов?

Класс (социальная группа) - класс (комната для занятий) - сословие - аудитория.

Мир (отсутствие войны) - мир (Вселенная) - безмятежность, покой – космос.

Брак (супружество) - брак (изделие с дефектом) - бракосочетание - отбраковать.

Вид (внешность, наружность) - вид (тип, разновидность) - ...

Мех (волосяной покров) - мех (приспособление для нагнетания воздуха)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Родственные слова имеют одинаковый корень***. Но однокоренные (родственные) слова каждого из омонимов будут разными в зависимости от значения омонимичного корня. Поэтому попробуйте работать в таком ключе:

КЛАСС - классовый, деклассированный...; КЛАСС - классный, внеклассный...;

мир-мирный, смирный, мирить...; мир - мировой, всемирный....

И так далее. Ряды сами постройте. Удачи!

Answer (score 0):

Да, совершенно правильно! Вы молодец, продолжайте - уверена, у Вас получится!
Кстати, мир раньше разделялся на "мiр" и "мир". Первое было в значении "Вселенная", а второе - "отсутствие войны" (если я не перепутала)))